# The order of $a$ in multiplicative group modulo prime $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p$ is a prime factor of something. By Fermat's Little Theorem I know that $ a^{ p-1 } \equiv 1 \mod p$. Can I say definitively that the order of $a$ is $p-1$?

Comment: Just pick $a=1$....

Comment: In general if $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, you will have the order of $a$ dividing $p-1$, but not necessarily equal to $p-1$.  However, there do exist numbers having order exactly $p-1$, and up to congruence modulo $p$ there are exactly $\varphi(p-1)$ of them ($\varphi$ is the Euler-phi function).  They are called "primitive roots."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's false in generally  is true that the order of $a$ divides $p-1$

Answer (score 1):

No.

First of all, Fermat's Little Theorem holds for $a\ne 0$.

Now, try with $a=1$. His order is $1$, not $p-1$.

The only sure thing you can say is "every $a\ne 0$ has an order that divides $p-1$"